# Remove a piece of text using Regex in C# .NET

Tags: .net, regex

I don't know regular expressions, and for only a small task, I don't want to sit and learn them - not to mention they seem very complicated. The thing I want to do is to pass a paragraph to a method and remove a piece of text that starts with parameter "begin" and ends with parameter "end".

```
    public static string RemoveBetween(string wholeText, string begin, string end) 
    { 

    }
```

Ex:

```
string myString = "one two three four five";
myString = RemoveBetween(myString, "two", "four");
```

The final string would be "one five"

Comment: What's the expected behavior if `end` is before `begin` in the string (e.g `RemoveBetween(myString, "four", "two")`)? Or if `begin`, or `end`, is not found? What if there are multiple occurrences of `begin` or `end`, or both?

Comment: You don't really have to use regular expressions to achieve your goal. It's a shame you don't want to "sit and learn them". Regular expressions are very useful for software developers to know.

Comment: @BertrandM end is never before begin, but there might be recursion involved. In that case, I need to remove all children and grandchildren. If begin and end are not found, simply return the existing string. The caller assumes that either begin and end are not found or they are both found.

Comment: @Bernard I know they are useful, but I have such a limited time to finish an annoying task so I needed help with trimming text.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static string RemoveBetween(string wholeText, string begin, string end) 
{ 
    Regex.Replace(wholeText, String.Format("{0}.*?{1}", Regex.Escape(begin), Regex.Escape(end)), String.Empty);
}
```

Easy. Seriously, learn regular expressions; they take a whole lot of parsing and reduce it to a single line of code.

As a comparison, here's something approximating what you'd have to do without a Regex:

```
public static string RemoveBetween(string wholeText, string begin, string end) 
{ 
    var result = wholeString;
    var startIndex = result.IndexOf(begin);
    while(startIndex >=0)
    {
        var endIndex = result.IndexOf(end) + end.Length;
        //TODO: Define behavior for when the end string doesn't appear or is before the begin string
        result = result.Substring(0,startIndex) + result.Substring(endIndex+1, result.Length - endIndex);
        startIndex = result.IndexOf(begin);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to forget to escape special chars in the begin and end strings before using them in a regex.

Comment: @Qtax - I agree; this is just a simple example showing the concept.

Comment: You can escape the begin and end strings with the Regex.Escape static method. This way users need not know that you are using regular expressions (or to avoid characters like $ or <

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example, done in steps so its easier to understand whats going on,

```
public static string RemoveBetween(string wholeText, string begin, string end) 
{
    int indexOfBegin = wholeText.IndexOf(begin);
    int IndexOfEnd = wholeText.IndexOf(end);

    int lenght = IndexOfEnd + end.Length - indexOfBegin;

    string removedString = wholeText.Substring(indexOfBegin, lenght);

    return  wholeText.Replace(removedString, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't need regular expressions for that, and it will be easier for you to check the input if your don't use them.

```
public static string RemoveBetween( string wholeText, string begin, string end ) {
    var beginIndex = wholeText.IndexOf( begin );
    var endIndex = wholeText.IndexOf( end );

    if( beginIndex < 0 || endIndex < 0 || beginIndex >= endIndex ) {
        return wholeText;
    }

    return wholeText.Remove( beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex + end.Length );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe like this.

```
string myString = "one two three four five";
        myString = myString.Substring(0, myString.IndexOf("two")) + myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf("four") + "four".Length);
```

Comment: I tried and it worked, just know that it is not a good practice, but it should work for him